# Compilation error due to (non-existant) import of react-refresh

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-refresh

We are currently working on a tiny app which just renders an external React component (external since it's `npm install`ed). The purpose of this app is to just fetch some JSON configuration and pass that as prop to that component to demonstrate its usage.

This app was created by create-react-app and its only changes to the scaffolded app are the contents of the index.tsx and App.tsx files. Well, there are also two JSON files added to the public directory.

### The problem: Compilation failed.

The problem now is, that this project compiles and runs on the machines of my co-workers but not on my machine. After `npm ci` and `npm start` I get the following:

```
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /home/newlukai/story/app/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.
assets by path static/js/*.js 4.81 MiB
  asset static/js/bundle.js 4.8 MiB [emitted] (name: main) 1 related asset
  asset static/js/node_modules_web-vitals_dist_web-vitals_js.chunk.js 6.56 KiB [emitted] 1 related asset
asset index.html 1.63 KiB [emitted]
asset asset-manifest.json 458 bytes [emitted]
988 modules

ERROR in ./src/App.tsx 1:40-155
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /home/newlukai/story/app/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.
 @ ./src/index.tsx 9:0-28 13:35-38

ERROR in ./src/index.tsx 1:40-155
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /home/newlukai/story/app/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

ERROR in ./src/reportWebVitals.ts 1:40-155
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /home/newlukai/story/app/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.
 @ ./src/index.tsx 7:0-48 31:0-15

webpack 5.69.1 compiled with 3 errors in 7225 ms
No issues found.
```

### The big question mark

The reason why I'm asking for support is: there is no explicit import of "react-refresh" in any of those files. The mentioned index.tsx looks like

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {HashRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import './index.scss';
import {App} from './App';


ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Router>
            <App />
        </Router>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. Learn more: <bit.ly link hidden due to SO inspection>
reportWebVitals();
```

### My approaches

So far I successfully tried to

- run `FAST_REFRESH=false npm start` (which effectively turns of fast refresh provided by react-refresh)
- create a new React app (`npx create-react-app@latest my-react-app --template typescript`) and copy the file contents to the new app

Creating a new directory and executing the following did not work:

```sh
cd newdirectory
cp <project>/package.json .
cp <project>/package-lock.json .
cp <project>/README.md .
cp <project>/tsconfig.json .
cp -r <project>/public .
cp -r <project>/src .
npm ci
npm start
```

### What really bothers me

- Two co-workers use Windows, another one and me are running Linux (Manjaro and Ubuntu). Windows works fine, the problem only occurs on Linux. But so far I did not find any hint that the OS might be the reason (all files use LF endings, no special file attributes found on `ls -la`).
- The lines in the error message (lines 7 and 9) don't match `import` statements in the `index.tsx` file. So I guess there is some injection done by the compilation process to enable fast refresh. Is it possible to print this changed file?
- There are three error messages, but only two carry line numbers. When I disable the `import`s of `App` and `reportWebVitals` (and change the usages accordingly) only one compilation error remains complaining about the not found module. But it does not tell anything about the line it refers to:

  ```
  Failed to compile.

  Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /home/jens/git/technology-consulting/formats/interactive-story/app/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
  You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.
  asset static/js/bundle.js 1.61 MiB [emitted] (name: main) 1 related asset
  asset index.html 1.63 KiB [emitted]
  asset asset-manifest.json 190 bytes [emitted]
  runtime modules 28.2 KiB 13 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/ 1.48 MiB 124 modules
  modules by path ./src/ 6.36 KiB
    ./src/index.tsx 2.1 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./src/index.scss 3.05 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[3]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[4]!./src/index.scss 1.2 KiB [built] [code generated]

  ERROR in ./src/index.tsx 1:40-155
  Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /home/newlukai/story/app/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
  You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

  webpack 5.69.1 compiled with 1 error in 3875 ms
  No issues found.
  ```

### Conclusion

I don't have any clue why this happens. And why this seem to happen on Linux only. I tried already to `rm -rf` the project, `git clone` it again and `npm cache clean --force` before `npm ci`. But that did not work.

Is there anybody with some React, React compilation and react-refresh insights able to give a hint on how to narrow that issue down?

Comment: Have you tried the traditional: delete node_modules, delete package-lock.json, npm install?

Comment: Dammit. That did the trick. I already tried rm -rf node_modules, npm install. But without deletion of package-lock.json. I did not assume that package-lock.json would disturb npm i. Thanks for that hint. Do you have an idea what's wrong then?

Comment: UPDATE: Somehow the colleagues managed to have a relative path in the package-lock.json. We will investigate on this. But I'm still wondering why that influences npm i.

Comment: The clue is that it failed for you and worked for others. So far I've found that's often the solution in such cases but I couldn't say why :)

Comment: Another important step in my scenario was to `npm uninstall react-refresh`. For some reason it was also specified as dependency for that simple app …
Do you mind if I write an answer or do you want to?

Comment: Adding an explicit dependency (+ version) of `react-refresh` in my `package.json` file fixed this for me. Specifically using version: `"0.11.0"` (tried with `0.13.0` and had the same issue).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The problem now is, that this project compiles and runs on the machines of my co-workers but not on my machine

This jumps out to me as a significant factor, to which the first solution I suggest is:

1. Delete node_modules
2. Delete package-lock.json
3. npm install

Both node_modules and package-lock are local to the build and can be safely deleted and will be automatically replaced by npm install.

Comment: This unblocked me. I had tried just about everything except deleting the package-lock.json. Definitely my fault that I was switching between yarn and npm :P

Answer (score 4):

Running yarn over npm solves the issues. Yarn needs to be installed globally.

With npm: `npm install --global yarn`
or with homebrew: `brew install yarn`

1. Remove node_modules folder `rm -rf node_modules`
2. Remove package-lock.json `rm package-lock.json`
3. Update Storybook `npx sb upgrade`
4. To re-install packages run `yarn`
5. To run storybook `yarn storybook`
6. To run react app `yarn start`

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion will be to first check for any conflict versions of internal dependencies.

In my case it happened because of react scripts conflict version.

1. Run `npm ls react-refresh` and it shows a different of react-refresh package versions

[image: screenshot1]

2. Run `npm dedupe --force` to de-duplicate versions
3. Run `npm ls react-refresh` to check versions of react-refresh

[image: screenshot2]

4. Then run npm start successfully.